# How to send -u data of Curl in Rest client

Tags: java, curl

I have a Curl request like:

curl -u "key:value" -H "headers" https://example.com

So, when I try to create a Rest client using this curl request in Java I am confused where to send the -u data in my request. Do we need to send it in Header or as URL parameter. Can somebody help me and tell me how can I send this -u in my Java code?

This is the code I am using:

```
URL url = new URL("https://example.com");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Headers", "Value");

***conn.setRequestProperty("u", "key:Value");***
```

Comment: The dafault auth type for cURL is [Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). So you need a header `Authorization: Basic base64encoded(user:pass)` where `base64encoded(key:value)` is actual String that is `key:value` base 64 encoded. You can encode it manually for testing [here](https://www.base64encode.org/). Or find a library that can do it. Java 8 comes with [`Base64.Encoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html)

Comment: If you add the `-v` (verbose, or just `-i` for headers only) switch to the cURL command, you can see all the headers. You can just copy it from there. bURL does the encoding behind the scenes, so you will see the encoded string

Comment: And you do realize that the `-u` switch is for username and password right? If you want to send entity data, it's with the `-d` switch

Comment: Great answer, couldn't find this anywhere else. Also, if using JS you can use btoa() function to encode to base64 string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The header Authorization: Basic base64encoded(user:pass) works for this question.